# Access Value of HTML Element Created in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

**EDIT:** This question is not a duplicate, I am aware that at this point foo has not been inserted into the DOM. My question is whether or not is is possible to access the elements declared in the string assigned to `foo` *without* inserting it into the document object.

In the following code, we declare an HTML element as a JavaScript variable.

```
<script>
var foo = "<td id = 'bar'>";
</script>
```

Now, after the `<script>` tag but before the `</script>` tag, how do I access the value of `id` in the table cell?

Eg. calling `console.log(foo.id)` obviously prints `undefined`.
how could I call the `console.log()` function (or any other function to access the value of `id`) to give us the correct value, `"bar"`?

Im using `<td>` as an example but I assume this applies to any html tag declared with JS.

Comment: it is not a DOM element until you actually put it in the DOM. The way you have it written it is just a string.

Comment: @Chase I actually made a mistake in the code I wrote. Updated with explanation. I am aware that it is not a DOM element at this point, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way to access the `id` element from the JS variable itself.

Comment: Since it's not a DOM element at this point and it's just a string, the only thing you can do is parse the string using string functions.

Comment: @raphael75 that is not entirely true (see my answer below), however since it's not a valid HTML string, the options are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you'd get what's between the first and second `'`, which coincidentally happens to be the id by doing:

```
foo.split("'")[1] // -> bar
```

However that is not too useful or reusable. You could push an element to memory and set the `innerHTML` of that node to your string, however the string in your example is not valid HTML, so it would not work.

```
var temp = document.createElement('html')
temp.innerHTML = str
temp.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].id // -> bar
```

Can't imagine your use case though, so maybe none are perfect.

Comment: That's more or less what I figured. Thanks!